# como usar mysql de wordpress en docker para crear otra base de datos

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

**como usar mysql de wordpress en docker para crear otra base de datos**
Consultando en docker el puerto no esta esta expuesto para acceder desde workbench para gestionar la base de datos.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9snXE.png)

```
version: "3"
    
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}
```

agradesco sus recomedacionones .

estoy intentando conectar con la base de datos. desde workbench o dbeaver y tego erro en la conexion
esto es el documento de docker-compose como puedo hacer para tener el puerto de coxion para poder acceder.

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que exponer el puerto del contenedor de `mysql` con el de tu computadora. Para ello debes agregar el campo `ports` en tu `docker-compose`.

```
version: "3"
    
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}
```

Finalmente en workbench usas la siguiente configuración para la conexión:

```
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 3306
```

Comment: Otra opción sería no abrir el puerto, y en su lugar añadir un nuevo docker (por ej con adminer). Este último ya estará en la red del DB y podrá acceder a ella desde el adminer